# Is there a way to create a JSON record to store in elasticsearch that only has the tip UUID?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm somewhat familiar to JSON and ElasticSearch through Java but I was requested to make an implementation that helps store elasticsearch data while minding the fact that there will be an expansion of the number of mapped values.

Can anyone give me cookie crumb trail on how to start this and where I should go from there?

Comment: what is a tip UUID?

Comment: @barrypicker a tip is the data my customer's program consumes and processes, and each tip has a UUID associated to it.

Comment: If you are using Fluentd for record collection, then you can filter unwanted data before storing them into Elasticsearch.